# go+doing with the right position of a complement

Tags: grammar

Do you agree with me on my estimation of 1 and 2? Now, I wonder whether 3 and 4 are correct.

1) Let's go mushroom-picking. - **correct**

2) Let's go picking mushrooms. - **wrong**

3) I like to go mushroom-picking in Summer. - ???

4) I like to go picking mushrooms in Summer. - ???

Comment: They all seem fine, except I would say "in the summer".

Comment: Well, 2 i definitely wrong. That's why I have a strong concern about 4.

Comment: Oh, then you'll have to find someone else who speaks the same version of English you do to write an answer.  In my version of English it's fine.  Maybe I got a lemon!

Comment: *Let's go picking mushrooms* is okay I think. *Let's go verb-ing + noun* is the structure. Maybe, another example is *Let's go walking downtown.* Others commenting on this could be useful though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your examples 1 and 3 are almost idiomatic. The hyphen is not necessary in this case--why not is complicated and I won't clutter up this answer with it here.

Your examples 2 and 4 are not very idiomatic as written. It would, however, be perfectly idiomatic to restate number 4 either as:

> I like to go mushroom picking in the summer

or as:

> I like to pick mushrooms in the summer

The situation is different when there is a preposition in the mix. So, for example, it would be idiomatic to say:

> I like to go foraging for mushrooms in the summer

but "go for mushrooms foraging" does not work in this context.

Answer (score 0):

2 and 4 are incorrect. 
Corrected it would be:

1. Let's go mushroom picking.
2. Let's go pick mushrooms.
3. I like to go mushroom picking in Summer. OR I like to go mushroom picking in the Summer.
4. I like to go pick mushrooms in Summer. OR I like to go pick mushrooms in the Summer.

"in Summer" or "in the Summer" both work for an unspecified Summer.
For a particular Summer you would use the "the".

I picked mushrooms in the Summer of 1980.

Comment: The name of this thread is "go+doing..." hence, "to go + bare infinitive" is out of scope, though a possible alternative. But I am not interested in alternatives. I need to know whether 2 and 4 are correct.